# Node azure blobService.generateSharedAccessSignature() returns an incorrect token

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to generate a shared access signature with the azure node SDK, but the returned token is not working/missing some params.

Im creating the token with:

```
app.get('/node-api/get-azure-token', (req, res, next) => {
  var blobService = azure.createBlobService(myStorageAccount, myAccessKey);
  var container = 'my-azure-container-name';
  var startDate = new Date();
  var expiryDate = new Date(startDate);
  expiryDate.setMinutes(startDate.getMinutes() + 10);
  startDate.setMinutes(startDate.getMinutes() - 5);

  var sharedAccessPolicy = {
    AccessPolicy: {
        ServiceVersion: '2016-05-31',
        Permissions: azure.BlobUtilities.SharedAccessPermissions.READ + azure.BlobUtilities.SharedAccessPermissions.WRITE + azure.BlobUtilities.SharedAccessPermissions.DELETE + azure.BlobUtilities.SharedAccessPermissions.LIST + azure.BlobUtilities.SharedAccessPermissions.ADD + azure.BlobUtilities.SharedAccessPermissions.CREATE,
        Start: startDate,
        Expiry: expiryDate,
        Protocols: 'https,http'
    }
};

    const key = blobService.generateSharedAccessSignature(container, req.query.bloburi, sharedAccessPolicy);

    res.send(key);
});
```

The error 'Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.' is thrown when using the generated sas token.

Has anyone come across this issue?

Comment: Can you share the shared access signature returned? Also what are you sending in `req.query.bloburi`? Is it the full blob URI?

Comment: @GauravMantri I actually just figured it out! I had the permissions in the wrong order. They need to be in the order shown here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/Constructing-a-Service-SAS?redirectedfrom=MSDN. This is not very clear in the docs!

Comment: Awesome! Would you mind putting that as an answer as it will **definitely** help other folks.

Comment: @GauravMantri just did! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I just figured it out! The order of permissions in the AccessPolicy object needs to be in the order shown here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/Constructing-a-Service-SAS?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Answer (score 0):

We adapted your code to our convenience and it works.

We give 100 mins of reading permissions (we use this to privatise images) and we moved the storage account name, access key, and container into global variables inside the .env file.

```
var azure = require('azure-storage');

var GetSharedAccessToken = function (blobName) {

const blobService = azure.createBlobService(process.env.EXPRESS_API_AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME, process.env.EXPRESS_API_AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_ACCESS_KEY);
const containerName = process.env.EXPRESS_API_AZURE_STORAGE_CONTAINER_NAME;

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
        var startDate = new Date();
        var expiryDate = new Date(startDate);
        expiryDate.setMinutes(startDate.getMinutes() + 100);
        startDate.setMinutes(startDate.getMinutes() - 100);
        var sharedAccessPolicy = {
            AccessPolicy: {
                Permissions: azure.BlobUtilities.SharedAccessPermissions.READ,
                Start: startDate,
                Expiry: expiryDate
            }
        };
        var token = blobService.generateSharedAccessSignature(containerName, blobName, sharedAccessPolicy);
        var sasUrl = blobService.getUrl(containerName, blobName, token);
        resolve(sasUrl);
    }
    catch (error) {
        reject(error);
    }
})}
```

The blobName in our case is the path in Azure of the image and we dynamically pass it when the user clicks on one of them.

Obviously, make sure you set your container's permissions to "Private" (no anonymous access) in "change access level".